# SQL- How to get the sum of each row and put it if condition exists, if does not exists put it in the last line

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this (There are many more names)

```
name    Class Amount
Alex    C1     100
Brenda  AB     50        
Brenda  C1     100         
Alex    AB     200
```

I would like the follow output, Sum the total for each Name but put it only if column Class equals C1 or or if there is no C1 put it in the last record of the name.

eg. The sum of Alex is 300(100+200), and from Brenda is 150(100+50), Alex have C1 in the first row so the sum is put in that row and not in the last one, brenda doesn´t have Class C1, so the sum is in the last row of Brenda.

Like this:

```
name    Class Amount   Sum
Alex    C1     100     300
Brenda  AB     50       0
Brenda  AB     100     150    
Alex    AB     200      0
```

Any idea how to do it in SQL? (Access or MySQL)

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in MySQL:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name order by (class = 'C1') desc, amount desc) = 1
             then sum(amount) over (partition by name)
             else 0
        end) as sum_amount
from t;
```